# Swift 4 & Firebase message being duplicated when they are received

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

For some reason when the user is receiving a message, the past messages are being duplicated. It's weird because the user who sends the messages are not having their messages duplicated when they send the message. Any help with my code would be much appreciated.

```
var messages =  [Message]()
fileprivate func observeMessages() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let userId = user?.uid else { return }

    if currentKey == nil {

        let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-message").child(uid).child(userId).queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
            guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in

                let messageId = snapshot.key

                let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                    let message = Message(dictionary: dict)

                    self.messages.append(message)
                    self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in
                        return message1.timeStamp.compare(message2.timeStamp) == .orderedDescending
                    })
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
            })
            self.currentKey = first.key

        }

    } else {

        let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-message").child(uid).child(userId).queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: self.currentKey).queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
            guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.key != self.currentKey {

                    let messageId = snapshot.key

                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                        let message = Message(dictionary: dict)

                        self.messages.append(message)
                        self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in
                            return message1.timeStamp.compare(message2.timeStamp) == .orderedDescending
                        })
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            })
            self.currentKey = first.key
        }
    }
}
```

The only places `observeMessages()` is being called is in `willDisplay` as shown below and in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if messages.count > 2 {
        if indexPath.item == messages.count - 1 {
            observeMessages()
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between the user sending and user receiving message is when the user sends a message and the submit message button is pressed, I call `self.messages.removeAll()` and then call `self.observeMessages()` again which seems to work because the user who sends the message doesn't have duplicate messages.

Comment: you have used .value , instead you should use childAdded i think, then it will only get the latest added child and not the previous ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have used .value , instead you should use childAdded i think, then it will only get the latest added child and not the previous ones.

```
 let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-message").child(uid).child(userId).queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
```